# LINQ Query for Regular Expression

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have a simple query that I need to use to obtain companies that begin with a special character or number instead of an alphabet.

```
 SELECT * FROM Company WHERE CompanyName LIKE '[^a-zA-Z ]%'
```

My Question is, how would I convert this into a LINQ query? I'd like to use this query with paging so LINQ to SQL seems the best option, but I couldn't find anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a regex here (or `like`)
If there's an index on Company.CompanyName, you would be better off with something like the following.

```
SELECT * FROM Company WHERE CompanyName < 'A' or CompanyName > 'z'
```

That will select everthing that doesn't start with A-Z, and will use any indexes available.

Comment: Hello, that's a slick way to do querying. Was wondering if you could provide me with a linq equivalent. I tried but can't find a solution for the same.

Comment: Anup: Sorry but I'm not an expert on Linq to SQL, it was more that I saw you were using a regex, which wouldn't exercise indexes, and I saw a way to fix that. Sorry I can't be more help.